# Sumproduct with multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I'm currently using Sum Product to rank year over year data from largest to smallest.  My formula in Column Z is `SUMPRODUCT(--(ABS($Y$5:$Y$165)>ABS(Y5)))+1` using the data in column Y.  The year over year data is in columns W and X.  I want to write a formula that does the same thing as far as ranking the data from largest to smallest but I want to exclude the points that may be zero in column W and X.  Because if there's no prior or latter data points--meaning that they're zero--I want them excluded.

For example

```
Column W | Column X | Column Y | Column Z

May14    |  May13   |   (YOY)  |   Rank

3228     |    0     |   3228   |    1
1324     |   1309   |    15    |    2
```

[image]

Comment: please clean up your explanation and add a screenshot and proper formatting.

Comment: Can you explain: A. what does your `sumproduct` formula do? (What values are there in y5-y165, what part does the > y5 play, etc...) B. what are the other values?

Comment: Amid in Y5:Y165 its the difference of the year over year values.  For example May 14 2,000 May 13 0 so in column Y it will be 2,000.  In column Z is the sumproduct formula which is a way to do a large if that excludes zeros.

Comment: Are you trying to exclude rows that have a 0 in columns W and X?  Or any rows that have a 0 in W or X?

Comment: TMH885 Correct I want to exclude and 0 in column W and X because when I'm ranking the YOY data it skews.  So I want to filter those data points out.

Comment: So you're looking to modify your formula in column Z to flag those rows that have a 0 in columns W and X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is add an IF statement to your formula in column Z:
`IF(AND(W5=0,X5=0),0,SUMPRODUCT(--(ABS($Y$5:$Y$165)>ABS(Y5)))+1)`

This will make the value in column Z equal to 0 if both W and X are 0.  Then you can easily filter these 0s out.

Comment: I tried that with OR instead of AND but than the values in Z doesn't go consecutively anymore.   The numbers go from 1 to 6 totally excluding 2,3,4,5.

Comment: You would need to exclude the zero rows in the SUMPRODUCT formula too. I don't think you've really made it clear whether you are only excluding rows with zero in both W and X (or in either) but based on TMH8885's assumption (that you only exclude when both are zero) you'd need this version `=IF(AND(W5=0,X5=0),0,SUMPRODUCT(--(ABS(Y$5:Y$165)>ABS(Y5)),--(W$5:W$165=0),--(X$5:X$165=0))+1)`

Comment: Barry Houdini it's either not both.

Comment: Barry that formula just place 0 in the rows fitting the criteria and everything else is number 1 not sequential.

Comment: Sorry, small error - retested and used this version - `=IF(OR(W5=0,X5=0),"",SUMPRODUCT(--(ABS(Y$5:Y$165)>ABS(Y5)),--((W$5:W$165=0)+(X$5:X$165=0)=0))+1)`

Comment: Barry Houdini Thanks atons!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind guys What I did if just created the IF outlier in the YOY calculation.  So in column Y, IF(OR(W6=0,X6=0,),0,W6-X6).  By just making the value 0 from that point the sumproduct is able to exclude that outlier.